# Querying which customers to be invoiced in a given date interval

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry about the title - I couldn't come up with a better one. I have an invoicing system and I need to calculate which customer agreements (contracts) will be invoiced in a given date interval. A contract runs for a period of time defined by the `start_date` and `end_date` date columns, where the duration is always in months (i.e. a natural number of months). The customer is invoiced every `invoice_interval` month, which is defined on every contract. If this column contains the number 3, the customer is invoiced every three months. What I need is to know which contracts/agreements will be invoiced between two dates. The dates will be the 21st of one month and the 20th of the following month, both included - e.g. between `2014-05-21` and `2014-06-20`.

Based on the `start_date` and `end_date`, this can be calculated by adding `invoice_interval` months to `start_date` a given number of times, e.g. with `DATE_ADD()`. If any of these dates are between X and Y, there is a match. The thing is that I do not know how to do this with an SQL query and without a loop. I did something similar when I needed to know if a contract would be invoiced in a given month (June 2014 in this example):

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts
WHERE start_date <= '2014-06-01'
AND end_date >= '2014-06-30'
AND (PERIOD_DIFF('2014-06-01', DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y%m')) % invoice_interval) = 0
```

The logic here is to check whether the difference in months between `start_date` and the month that I am checking divided by `invoice_interval` has no rest - by using modulus. If so, the contract should be invoiced in that month.

So, I need to change the above query to figure out if a contract should be invoiced between `2014-05-21` and `2014-06-20`, for example. Let's say that a contract starts on `2014-01-14` and ends on `2015-01-14` and is invoiced every 3 months. I want to find the contracts that will be invoiced between `2014-03-21` and `2014-04-20`. This given contract should be in the result set because it will be invoiced on `2014-04-14`, `2014-07-14` and `2014-10-14`. How can I accomplish this? Much preferable in an SQL query like the above.

I hope I explained the problem well enough. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things let's write function, which calculates full months count between two dates:

```
-- how many full months between d1 and d2
CREATE FUNCTION month_count(d1 DATE, d2 DATE)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE count INT;

  SET count = PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d1), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d2));
  -- correction
  RETURN IF(DAY(d1) >= DAY(d2), count, count-1);
END;
```

The query then:

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts
WHERE start_date <= @y AND end_date >= @x
  -- check invoice interval
  AND month_count(@y, start_date) > 0
  AND (month_count(@y, start_date) % invoice_interval) = 0
  -- check what invoice date is before contract end
  AND DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL month_count(@y, start_date) MONTH) <= end_date
```

Replace `@x` with interval start date (for example: '2014-05-21') and `@y` with interval end date (for example: '2014-06-20').

Please note that this solution correctly works only if:

1. There are exactly one month between two invoice interval dates (as specified in your question)
2. Interval end date satisfies the condition: (day of month) <= 28

To work around the second issue use modified function (this function counts 1 month between dates '2014-02-28' and '2014-01-31'):

```
-- how many full months between d1 and d2
CREATE FUNCTION month_count(d1 DATE, d2 DATE)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE count INT;

  SET count = PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d1), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d2));
  -- correction
  RETURN IF(DAY(d1) = DAY(LAST_DAY(d1)) OR DAY(d1) >= DAY(d2), count, count-1);
END;
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! I've made a few tweaks to it so that contracts are not invoiced for an additional period in their ending month. So far everything looks OK, but I will continue to test it out. Thanks a lot for your answer!